# How to get vendor name of serial COM port using DeviceIoControl()?

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

Is it possible to get vendor name of serial COM port using DeviceIoControl()?

Comment: Serial ports are "dumb" devices.  They do not provide any kind of self identification.  You're asking about a characteristic of an "intelligent" device such as a USB device (that has a processor).

Comment: I connected prolific USB to serial adapter in my machine.I am able to get manufacture name as "Prolific" using WMI services by executing the WQL query "SELECT Manufacturer FROM Win32_PnPEntity where Name LIKE '%COM4%". Likewise is it possible to get the manufacture name from port name using DeviceIoControl.

Comment: The only way to get that information via and IOCTL call is if the vendor specific driver supports it (and you can access the spec on how to use it, or reverse engineer it). Instead, use the standard SetupDi calls to find information about the USB device and descriptors itself since you already know the VID/PID.